# How to get & set environment variables in Scala?

Tags: scala, shell, environment-variables

I want to set Scala variable to environmental variables and get the variable in shell scripting.

Comment: Is the shell supposed to be a subprocess of your java process?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin, Yes

Comment: See [here](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-set-environment-variables-running-external-commands/)

Answer (score 0):

#### Setting environment variables

The [companion object of `scala.sys.process.Process`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.4/scala/sys/process/Process$.html) has several `apply` factory methods that allow you to specify various parameters, such as

- the arguments passed to the executable
- current working directory of the started process
- extra environment variables

For example:

```
import scala.sys.process.Process
import java.io.File

Process(
  List("bash", "-c", """echo "pwd=$(pwd) FOOBAR=${FOOBAR}";"""),
  Some(new java.io.File("..")),
  "FOOBAR" -> "42"
).!!
```

will start `bash` in the parent directory of your current working directory, with an additional environment variable `FOOBAR` set to `"42"`.

#### Getting environment variables

Works in exactly the same way as for Java, with `System.getenv`.

For example, if you start `scala`/`scala3` from your terminal with

```
BARFOO="someValue" scala3
```

and then in the Scala-REPL run

```
System.getenv("BARFOO")
```

then it will return

```
"someValue"
```